# converting Godeps/Godeps.json: malformed file path

Tags: go, dependencies

I am playing around with a project [from here](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/contrib) that uses a `Godephs.json`. I would like to install the dependencies. To do that I run `go mod init`. The first couple dependencies are downloaded fine, but the I run into

```
converting Godeps/Godeps.json: stat github.com/docker/distribution/reference@cd27f179f2c10c5d300e6d09025b538c475b0d51: create zip: contrib/docker-integration/generated_certs.d/localregistry:5440/ca.crt: malformed file path "contrib/docker-integration/generated_certs.d/localregistry:5440/ca.crt": invalid char ':'
contrib/docker-integration/generated_certs.d/localregistry:5441/ca.crt: malformed file path "contrib/docker-integration/generated_certs.d/localregistry:5441/ca.crt": invalid char ':'
```

How can I fix this? I do not even know how to approach this.

Comment: You cannot. Update your go.mod manually using valid (i.e. usable with modules) versions of your dependencies.

Comment: I have no idea what the dependencies of this project are. What exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **install all dependencies your Godeps in an unknown project**:

```bash
# what package is this? 
$ go mod init 
some_name

# throw away Godeps to not confuse go 
$ rm -rf Godeps

$ go mod tidy 

$ go mod init some_name
```